# what does "::" mean in Scala ?

Tags: scala, symbols

What does :: mean here ?

```
listeners ::= listener
list = num :: list
```

Specially I don't understand the "**::**" operator.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Comment: It's like `+:` but list-specific.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its the list *cons* operator. It creates a new list whose head is first argument and whose tail is contents of the second argument.